# C# & Twitter API: Getting tweets with specific #tag

Tags: asp.net, json, c#-4.0, twitter

I'm new to Twitter API & trying to get tweets with a specific hashtag in my C# Web application.
I was able to authenticate my app & get JSON from Twitter ,here are some questions/issues I have:

API can only return maximum 100 tweets in one call,so how I can check if I've more tweets?

If somebody have code example to convert that(Twitter's) JSON into custom class object,so 
I can count tweets (I tried but getting errors)?

I used [this](http://json2csharp.com) to generate c# classes from json & getting error while doing following:

```
JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
RootObject routes_list = (RootObject)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(s);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tweetinvi](https://tweetinvi.codeplex.com) manages that for you. Here is an example returning 200 results.

```
var searchParameter = Search.GenerateSearchTweetParameter("#my_tag");

searchParameter.Lang = Language.English;
searchParameter.SearchType = SearchResultType.Popular;
searchParameter.MaximumNumberOfResults = 200;
searchParameter.Since = new DateTime(2013, 12, 1);
// ... There are many different parameters that can be set

var tweets = Search.SearchTweets(searchParameter);
tweets.ForEach(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Text));

// Get number of objects
var nbTweets = tweets.Count();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello,

I was using this library initially,but having some [issue](https://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/workitem/2187),so I drop the idea of using this library.

Comment: The Twitter API can only return maximum 100 tweets in one call,so how I can check if I've more tweets?

Twitter API returns up to 100 tweets based on the count parameter you provide to the method. It does not mean you will receive all these tweets.

If you want to count the number of tweets or get them you can still use Tweetinvi ObjectConverter and just give the json you have received from your own call.

var searchQueryHelper = TweetinviContainer.Resolve<ISearchQueryHelper>();
var tweets = searchQueryHelper.GetTweetsFromJsonResponse(tweetsJson);

Comment: Hi, did the second solution I provided above solved your problem?

Comment: I haven't try the other solution yet.I'll update you once I try.

Comment: Did it worked? Would be happy to help you more if it does not!

Comment: Hello @user2465083,
I tried the other solution provided by Linvi [Here](https://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/workitem/2187).
Thanks you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Certainly Tweetinvi as user64 said, is a great API, please for version 2.1 the following does the job. Be aware of set RateLimitTrack mode

```
        // Set up my credentials in (https://apps.twitter.com)
        Auth.SetUserCredentials(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret);

        // Enable Automatic RateLimit handling
        RateLimit.RateLimitTrackerMode = RateLimitTrackerMode.TrackAndAwait;

        var searchParameter = Search.CreateTweetSearchParameter("#My_Tag");
        searchParameter.Lang = LanguageFilter.Spanish; // or English
        searchParameter.SearchType = SearchResultType.Recent;
        searchParameter.MaximumNumberOfResults = 200; // or any number 
        searchParameter.Since = new DateTime(2013, 12, 1);
        var tweets = Search.SearchTweets(searchParameter); // tweets.Count() has the actual searched tweets
        foreach(var item in tweets)
        {
            // do anything with item and its properties example: item.Text;
        }
```